# Замена одного поля в IPv4 заголовке UDP пакета перед отправкой

Tags: golang, ip, udp, сеть

Нужно сделать поле Identification заголовка IP пакета равным нулю, но не хочется прибегать к RAW-сокетам (не хочется делать большой велосипед).
Реально ли? Если да, то как?

Comment: Ответ может зависеть от операционной системы, не?

Comment: Вам нужно отправлять пакеты или слушать и отправлять? Только ipv4?

Answer (score 1):

Это поле используется протоколом IP для собственных нужд. Даже если вы найдете способ ставить там ноль - это еще не означает, что ноль придет к получателю.

Answer (score 0):

**UDP: все что раньше было ниже - глупость, я спутал уровни OSI и заголовки IP-пакетов со структурой их представления**

То что ты хочешь происходит в ядре ОС, а golang пользуется этим через системные вызовы [send, sendto, sendmsg](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sendmsg). Заголовки пакетов ядро отдаст тебе только в случае использования SOCK_RAW, который ты можешь получить через net.DialIP, net.ListenIP.

Так же есть пакет [golang.org/x/net/ipv4](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/ipv4), который упростит написание своей реализации для RAW-сокетов, там есть определения заголовков IP-пакетов и можно подсмотреть механизм их трансляции в бинарные данные.

http://play.golang.org/p/Uxcp48Jy3i

```
package main

import(
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "golang.org/x/net/ipv4"
    "time"
)
type my_conn struct {
    *ipv4.RawConn
}

func New_my_conn(conn net.PacketConn) net.PacketConn {
    c, _ := ipv4.NewRawConn(conn)
    return &my_conn{ c }
}

// И переопределить ReadFrom, WriteTo что бы они соответствовали интерфейсу net.PacketConn (остальные методы вроде на месте и с нужной сигнатурой)
func (conn *my_conn) WriteTo(b []byte, addr net.Addr) (n int, err error) {
    //Собираем заголовки
    //...
    //

    // WARNING: тут они куда то потеряли возвращаемое значение кол-ва записанных байт, так что придется, костылить
    return len(b), conn.RawConn.WriteTo(nil, b, nil)
}

func (conn *my_conn) ReadFrom(b []byte) (int, net.Addr, error) {
    hdr, buf, cm, err := conn.RawConn.ReadFrom(b)
    _, _ = hdr, cm
    // вытащить из заголовков net.Addr
    return len(buf), &net.UDPAddr{}, err
}

func (conn *my_conn) LocalAddr() (net.Addr){
    // выдернуть из сокета через reflect??
    return &net.UDPAddr{}
}

func main(){
    addr, _ := net.ResolveIPAddr("ip4", "127.0.0.1")

    conn, _ := net.ListenIP("ip4", addr)
    my_conn := New_my_conn(conn)

    go func(){
        //c, err := net.ListenIP("ip4", &net.IPAddr{ IP: net.IPv4zero }) 
        c, err := net.DialIP("ip4", nil, addr)
        fmt.Println(c, err)

        //n, err := c.WriteTo([]byte("Hello"), addr)
        n,err := c.Write([]byte{1,2,3})
        fmt.Println(n,err)
    }()

    time.Sleep(time.Second)
    buf := make([]byte, 100)
    n, laddr, err := my_conn.ReadFrom(buf)
    fmt.Println(n, err, laddr, buf)
}
```

Надеюсь принцип понятен.

И это только net.PacketConn, хочешь net.Conn - тогда тебя ждут еще Read, Write и RemoteAddr методы =)

PS А не проще твою задачу решить в фаерволле/модуле на уровне ядра?